# Are register declarations ignored by the compiler?

Tags: iphone, c, cocoa-touch, cpu-registers

When using plain C in iPhone development, does the compiler place the variables declared as `register` in a CPU register?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to know for sure is to look at the documentation for the compiler and if that doesn't describe what `register` does then it could do anything (within the parameters defined by the standard).

Comment: AFAIK Apple is using gcc, and I couldn't find any doc saying it is a modified version, so it's standard gcc I guess.

Answer (score 1):

`register` is only an advisory hint to the compiler; It doesn't guarantee that the variable will really be placed in a register.

If no spare registers are available, the variable would still be on the stack.

Comment: What I want to know is if it is ignored always, or instead the compiler will try to assign it to a register when possible.

Comment: it's never ignored, but as said, it's only an hint, not an order.

Comment: @ydroneaud How are you so sure? In K&R it is said that "compilers are free to ignore the advice". I'd like to know if this compiler will try to do something.

Comment: "A declaration of an identifier for an object with storage-class specifier register suggests that access to the object be as fast as possible. The extent to which such suggestions are effective is implementation-defined."

Comment: "The implementation may treat any register declaration simply as an auto declaration. However, whether or not addressable storage is actually used, the address of any part of an object declared with
storage-class specifier register cannot be computed, either explicitly (by use of the unary & operator as discussed in 6.5.3.2) or implicitly (by converting an array name to a pointer as discussed in 6.3.2.1). Thus, the only operator that can be applied to an array declared with storage-class specifier register is sizeof."

Comment: Using `register` is considered as bad practice in modern C programming, it is a form of "pre-mature optimization". On modern compilers, the compiler is far more capable that the programmer to decide whether to optimize a variable. Use of this keyword has been banned by MISRA-C, for example.

Comment: "The extent to which such suggestions are effective is implementation-defined" is interesting, since that means that a conforming implementation *must* document the extent. That's what "implementation-defined" means, as opposed to "unspecified". In practice, implementations frequently don't document everything that's implementation-defined, and I suspect that this is one that's especially likely to be left out.

Comment: @Lundin, I consider it as good practise actually. It is a promise to the compiler that you don't want to take the address of the variable.

Comment: @JensGustedt Why would the compiler need such a promise? Any modern compiler would surely be able to detect the presence of the unary & operator. Unless the `register`-declared variable is a member of a union, or something equally obscure.

Comment: @Lundin, making a `struct` a `register` is nothing obscure. This relaxes the compiler from the idea that the `struct` is some contiguous entity. `gcc` for example is good in tracking individual fields of such a `struct`. And then code changes in time. The moment I edit to use a `&` operator for such a variable the compiler shouts at me.

Comment: @JensGustedt, it is enforced by the compiler.

Comment: @AProgrammer, yeah, that's what I said, no?

Comment: @JensGustedt, a promise is weaker for me (but I'm not a native english speaker). I'd have used promise for describing variadic function argument passing for instance ("with printf, you promise that you pass arguments of types described in the format string").

Comment: @JensGustedt That's not what I said, declaring a union _member_ as "register" is obscure. And that's the only case I can come up with where the compiler cannot statically find out whether the contents of a memory cell are accessed through a pointer or not. My point is that you shouldn't need to use register for plain variables, as the compiler is obviously capable to find out whether the variable is accessed through & or not. And then it can optimize accordingly, without the so-called aid of the programmer.

Answer (score 0):

The `register` keyword doesn't refer to hardware registers of the CPU. It can't be, since you can declare any type of variable `register`, also those types that never would fit into a hardware register.

It is just contract with the compiler that you never will take the address of such a variable. Such a promise from you will ease the task of optimizing for the compiler. In particular your variable then never can alias, and more generally it can't change from outside the direct control flow.

Comment: wow downvoting without notice. is there something factually wrong here?